# Soap UI dynamic request and response

Tags: soapui

Soap UI Mock Service. I have an API with n no of requests like Request 1, Request 2, etc. Also i have corresponding n number of response in mock service like Response 1, Response 2, etc. 
My Requirement is when i run the Request 1 then i should get Response 1 and if Request 2 then Response 2.

I know there is a way to do this simple thing, but not getting the exact method to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the response dispatch you can switch to using an xpath or script dispatch and the use that to dynamically select the response.

Read this page, specifically the section on Mock Operation Dispatch:
 http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/simulating-complex-behaviour.html

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar question and it was resolved here:
[Solution to similar case in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029173/soapui-set-a-mockservice-test-property-in-the-middle-of-a-test-case)

I used scripts to set external values during a Test Case. Then I used this external value to decide which output to provide.