# SoapUI: set a MockService Test Property in the middle of a Test Case

Tags: groovy, soapui

Good day,

Brief illustration on what I am planning to achieve:

[image: image of the problem and theory for solution]

From within a Test Case I have a groovy script to set a Property for the current Test Case:

[image: image of a script with unfinished solution]

**The Question is: How can I modify (set) a MockService Property value from outside of the Mock Service itself. I know the solution lies in just adding the right syntax to the example above**

All the best

Comment: The urls are blocked for me right now so I cannot see what actually have you tried. Follow [Tips and Tricks](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#1-1-get-and-set-properties), specially "Start and stop MockServices" and look a the api for WsdlMockService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property in the mockservice context like that:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.mockServices["yourMockService"].getMockRunner().getMockContext().setProperty("yourProperty","yourPropertyValue")
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I can see some activity, but not quite what I expected.
The property that is added to the Mock Service is not being updated, but, the value is saved "somewhere" (i can retrieve it with getProperty("x")). Although I could use this solution (because I can retrieve the value when filtering which output to give from Mock Service response) it does not visually show what is the property value in the Mock Service Property.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution:

`testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.mockServices["yourMockService"].getMockRunner().getMockService().setPropertyValue("yourProperty","yourPropertyValue")`

Comment: Yes your are right, my solution allows to update a property in the context of the mockRunner, not  a property of the mockService. Glad I helped you to find out the solution.

Comment: I tried to add the information to the Answer, but It seems like it did not process. Can you add the info to your answer so that any finders can see the difference between mockContext and mockService ?
Also, the Mock Service must be running when script tries to set values, or else there is NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I DID NOT need either getMockRunner() or getMockService() to set a property for my mock.

This is what worked for me:

> testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.mockServices["your_mock"].setPropertyValue("your_property_name", "your_property_value")